# Add Radius to Dropdown

Tags: css

The vertical menu opens to the left when on a desktop or tablet. It opens down when on a smaller screen. I've managed to get the desired radii for the wide screens. Before it's opened on a small screen the radii are showing correctly. But, when it's opened on a small screen the radii are still there at the bottom, but not the top. When the bottom link is clicked, the bottom radii also disappear. The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/hozey/yrefmf9u/

```
    <style class="cp-pen-styles">
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body a:hover { color: #fff; }

nav { background-color: #2c3e50; 
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topleft:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topright:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px; 
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topleft:0px;
  -webkit-border-radius-topright:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
nav li,
nav .nav-toggle {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
nav .dropdown > a:after {
  content: 'V';
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
nav .dropdown.open,
.desktop nav li:hover { background-color: #34495e; }

nav .dropdown.open > a:after,
.desktop nav li:hover > a:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
nav .dropdown ul {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #34495e;
  display: none;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

/***** DESKTOP *****/
.desktop nav { width: 150px;
}

.desktop nav li {
  text-align: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.desktop nav li:hover ul {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  visibility: visible;  
}

.desktop nav .dropdown:hover > a:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg); 
}

.desktop nav .dropdown > a:after {
  content: '>';
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.desktop nav .dropdown ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  -ms-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.desktop nav .nav-toggle {
display: none;  
}

</style>
```

Please tell me how to get the top and bottom radii for the small screen view. Thank you.

Comment: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrefmf9u/1/) with included jQuery (do this on the left of the JSFiddle page) with reproducible problem (Firefox 37.0.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yrefmf9u/6/

Always check with your debugger (developer tools) what’s interfering.

The jQuery code toggles and displays a `<div>` at the position of the `<nav>` element and that div doesn’t have radii. Luckily, it has a class name: `nav-toggle`. You can use this class and apply `border-radius` to it as well. These are the relevant rules I’ve written — it should work for both desktop and mobile flawlessly:

```css
.nav-toggle, nav{
    border-radius:10px;
}

.nav-toggle.open{
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}

nav li:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}

nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

nav li.dropdown:not(.open):last-child{
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
```